# How do I go about the concept of group video chat?

Tags: android, video, chat, call

I am new to android ..I want to incorporate the idea of a video chat in my app ..how do I go about the concept of GROUP(2 or more) video chat / conference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google provides Audio/Video Library i.e. WebRTC. The library is in C++. You have to download the code compile it using Android NDK and include it on your project.

You will have to write the JNI layer to call the C++ Library functions to play Audio/Video.

Links :

http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html